# Watson conversation return different results for the same request

Tags: watson-conversation

I create one simple conversation dialogue, and I input the same question, but Watson returns different results. You can see the attached picture, the 1st time, Watson only matches the intent, but does not return the response message. I enter the same question again, it returns predefined response.
It seems that only even request, Watson can return response message. The odd request, Watson did not return message.
Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Try it out" window is good for simple checking, but not great if you want to know what is actually happening in the background.

I recommend to the deploy a [Conversation Simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) test app. This will allow you to query your conversation and easily see the request/response.

To help further debug then give your nodes meaningful names. Then in the JSON check the `nodes_visited` section. It might look something like this:

```
"nodes_visited": [
      "FLOW purchase dog",
      "Check for Mudi"
    ]
```

In this case, the user asked to buy a dog. First node then jumped to the second node "check for mudi", and that the node it is currently completed.

---

In your sample image, which might be happening is this:

[image]

1. First user input hits the first node.
2. At this point, Conversation is sitting at the speech bubble in the tree.
3. Next user input is checked in the branch, not the top level.
4. Conversation after finishing the branch, only then goes back to root.